# Reason behind the heat capacity of water

Tags: thermodynamics, energy

Water has a high specific capacity. Why can water release a large amount of energy without a great change in temperature?

Comment: More generally, you should be asking what factors affect heat capacity? The answer is density plus number of degrees of freedom ([read more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_capacity#Factors_that_affect_specific_heat_capacity)). Water molecules can translate, their bond lengths can oscillate, their bond angle can oscillate, they can rotate. So there are lots of places to 'store' energy.